# Incorrect directory permissions with OpenSSH on Cygwin on Windows Server 2008 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh, cygwin

I ran into a weird directory permission problem when logged in to a Win2008SP2 (not R2) server through SSH. When I open a local cygwin shell on the server, i can do this:

```
myUser@myServer ~
$ cd /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/inetsrv/

myUser@myServer /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/inetsrv
$ cd config

myUser@myServer /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/inetsrv/config
$
```

I have no issues accessing the 'config' directory when using a local cygwin shell. 'myUser' has all necessary permissions to access the directory as well. In fact, 'myUser' is a local administrator on the machine.

Listing the permissions of the config folder through the local cygwin shell shows the following output:

```
   4 drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM             0 Aug  2 09:38 config
```

But when I log into the server with a SSH client (in this case Putty), i run into the following problem:

```
myUser@myServer ~
$ cd /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/inetsrv/

myUser@myServer /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/inetsrv
$ cd config
-bash: cd: config: Permission denied
```

It also doesn't list the proper permissions through SSH:

```
0 drwxr-x---  1 ????????       ????????           0 Aug  2 09:38 config
```

When I look at the running processes on the server with Task Manager (with a remote desktop connection), it shows that all bash.exe processes are running under the 'myUser' account, so I don't understand why I can't access that particular directory through SSH but have no problems accessing it in a local cygwin shell.

I'm using OpenSSH 5.9p1-1. I'm not sure what the Cygwin version is... I used the latest setup.exe (version 2.738) of Cygwin, but I can't seem the find any other Cygwin-related version number.

I doubt that it's related to SSH/Cygwin though, because when I connect from the Win2008SP2 server to my local Win7 machine through SSH (using the same OpenSSH/Cygwin versions) I can access the /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/inetsrv/config folder without issues.

Does anyone have an idea on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be because the ssh service on the server running as a local 'sshd_server' user. Even though I was logged in with a domain user which has sufficient privileges, accessing the directory was blocked (for reasons that aren't clear to me) because of the sshd_user the service ran under.

The solution was to run the ssh service under a domain account which had sufficient privileges to access the folder, and then it worked.  I'm not entirely happy with this solution though, and would love to hear bet